# No Qualifying Bean When Bean is Defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, java-annotations

I have been trying to get a setup where I create the PostDatedAchInReader which implements JdbcCursorItemReader and then injected that into the PostDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader which collects read objects based on a specific criteria and groups them into a list keeping basically all the ach requests groups by client id.  However, I keep getting the no qualifying bean error and yet the bean is here and defined.  I am confused what the problem is or how to fix it.

So I have the following configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class PostDatedAchInBatchConfig extends AbstractCommonBatchJobConfig {

    private static final String ACH_FULFILLMENT_POST_DATED_ACH_IN_STEP1_NAME =
            "achFulfillment_postDatedAchInJob_step1_scheduleAchIns";

    @Autowired
    DataSource prodDataSource;

    /**
     * This method defines the Job.
     *
     * @return postdatedachinjob
     *         return the configured job.
     */
    @Bean(name = "achFulfillmentPostDatedAchInJob")
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        mmLogMgr.info("AchFulfillmentEmailBatchConfig : job");
        return getJobBuilderFactory().get("achFulfillmentPostDatedAchInJob")
                .listener(postDatedAchInListener())
                .start(step1())
                .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode())
                .end() // end of TransactionBuilder
                .end() // end of FlowBuilder
                .build();

    }

..

    /**
     * @return postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader.
     */
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
    public ItemReader<ArrayList<PostDatedAchIn>> postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader(@Qualifier("postDatedAchInReader") final PostDatedAchInReader postDatedAchInReader)
            throws Exception {
        PostDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader =
                new PostDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader();
        postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader.setDatabaseItemReader(postDatedAchInReader);
        return postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PostDatedAchInClassifierWriter postDatedAchInClassifierWriter() {
        Map<String, ItemWriter<PostDatedAchIn>> classMap = new HashMap<String, ItemWriter<PostDatedAchIn>>();
        classMap.put("true", postDatedAchInCompositeWriterOneTimeFailure());
        classMap.put("false", postDatedAchInCompositeWriterPosted());
        PostDatedAchInClassifierWriter classifyWriter = new PostDatedAchInClassifierWriter();
        classifyWriter.setClassMap(classMap);
        return classifyWriter;
    }


..

    @Bean(name = "postDatedAchInReader")
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
    public PostDatedAchInReader postDatedAchInReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['current.business.date']}") final String currentBusinessDate) {

        SqlStatementHelper sqlStatementHelper = new SqlStatementHelper(PostDatedAchInConstants.POST_DATED_ACH_IN_PROPERTY_FILE,
                PostDatedAchInConstants.POST_DATED_ACH_IN_PROPERTY_ALT_FILE);
        String sqlStatement = sqlStatementHelper.getSqlStatement(PostDatedAchInConstants.RETRIEVE_POST_DATED_ACH_IN);

        ArrayList<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();
        parameters.add(currentBusinessDate);
        parameters.add(currentBusinessDate);
        parameters.add(currentBusinessDate);

        ListPreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter = new ListPreparedStatementSetter();
        preparedStatementSetter.setParameters(parameters);

        PostDatedAchInReader postDatedAchInReader = new PostDatedAchInReader();
        postDatedAchInReader.setDataSource(prodDataSource);
        postDatedAchInReader.setSql(sqlStatement);
        postDatedAchInReader.setRowMapper(new PostDatedAchInRowMapper());
        postDatedAchInReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(preparedStatementSetter);

        return postDatedAchInReader;
    }

    /**
     * This method defines the Steps, it writes 1 record at a time.
     *
     * @return postdatedachinjob_step1
     *
     */
    @Bean(name = ACH_FULFILLMENT_POST_DATED_ACH_IN_STEP1_NAME)
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        mmLogMgr.info(ACH_FULFILLMENT_POST_DATED_ACH_IN_STEP1_NAME);
        return getStepBuilderFactory().get(ACH_FULFILLMENT_POST_DATED_ACH_IN_STEP1_NAME)
                .<ArrayList<PostDatedAchIn>, ArrayList<PostDatedAchIn>> chunk(AchFulfillmentBatchJobUtil
                        .getChunkValue("postdatedachin"))
                .reader(postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader(null))
                .processor(postDatedAchInProcessor())
                .writer(postDatedAchInClassifierWriter())
                .build();
    }

}
```

And when I run the job, I get the following stack trace:

```
2018-10-31 15:06:45,821 ERROR [o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:AbstractStep.java:execute:229 - main] - Encountered an error executing step achFulfillment_postDatedAchInJob_step1_scheduleAchIns in job achFulfillmentPostDatedAchInJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader' defined in com.tdameritrade.ctg.ach.batch.postdatedachinjob.PostDatedAchInBatchConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdameritrade.ctg.ach.batch.postdatedachinjob.PostDatedAchInReader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=postDatedAchInReader)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.tdameritrade.ctg.ach.fulfillment.util.MoneyMovementHelper.getJobExecution(MoneyMovementHelper.java:155)
    at com.tdameritrade.ctg.ach.fulfillment.util.MoneyMovementHelper.getJobExecution(MoneyMovementHelper.java:136)
    at com.tdameritrade.ctg.ach.batch.postdatedachinjob.PostDatedAchInBatchConfigTest.testLaunchJob(PostDatedAchInBatchConfigTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdameritrade.ctg.ach.batch.postdatedachinjob.PostDatedAchInReader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=postDatedAchInReader)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

I am confused how it says it can not find the bean of the type when it is defined right in the class.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we were able to fix this by changing the call to the aggregating reader in the step configuration to send the method/bean of the cursor reader.  We changed this line:

```
.reader(postDatedAchInAggregatingJdbcItemReader(postDatedAchInReader()))
```

And removed the @Qualifier.  This stopped this error and it does correctly wire everything up.  Feels a bit clunky to me but it works.  I am open to additional solutions if anyone has one.

Comment: In the old version you were literally passing `null` as the bean value in the old code, so I'm not so surprised that Spring was angry with you.